# How to find the difference between 2 times if the value in another column is 1

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have this sample data:

```
A           B   C          D    E    F
1/11/2015   1   6:00 PM         1   
1/11/2015   1   11:00 PM        1
1/12/2015   2   7:30 AM     1
1/12/2015   2   10:00 PM    1   
1/14/2015   4   2:00 AM     1
1/15/2015   5   9:00 AM         1   
1/16/2015   6   1:00 AM     1
```

I want to calculate the time in hours between the dates if the value in column E is 1.

I know the formula to calculate the time difference is =(A1+C1)-(A2+C2).

The issue is how to just calculate it if E is 1 and how to get it to handle the gap. (for example, the formula might be F2=(A1+C1)-(A2+C2) or it might be F4=(A1+C1)-(A4+C4).

thanks!

Comment: Are you always subtracting row 1 values from the current row?...or do you want to subtract the last row with a 1 in column E?

Comment: I want to subtract the last row with a 1 in E. @barryhoudini

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to subtract the date/time from the previous row with 1 in col E from the current row then you can use this approach in Excel (not tested for google).

Use this formula in F2 - custom format as **[h]:mm** and copy down column

`=IF(E2=1,A2+C2-LOOKUP(2,1/E$1:E1,A$1:A1+C$1:C1),"")`

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work in google sheets. I'm not sure why your search parameter is 2. I'm looking for when E is 1 right?

Comment: When I use just the lookup, I'll return A1+C1 only when E=1 (otherwise i get a #Div0 error). Say I'm in the 4th row and i change the search parameter to 1/E$1:E3 I'll get a #Value error.

thanks for the help